# The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement flask elasticsearch

Tags: html, elasticsearch, flask

i have problem with my flask and elasticsearch, i just wanna try to get my index content and show it to table but this is happend ?

this is my code:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask,request,redirect,render_template,jsonify,json
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch()
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/edan',methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        index = es.indices.get('*')
        valueindex = request.form['index1']
        resp2 = []
        key_list = []
        data = es.search(index=valueindex, body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
        for a in data["hits"]["hits"]:
            dict = {}
            for key in a["_source"].keys():
                if key not in key_list:
                    key_list.append(key)
                dict[key] = a["_source"][key]
            resp2.append(dict)
            return render_template('elastic.html',es=es,resp2=resp2,key_list= key_list,index=index)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

elastic.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Elastic GUI</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <br>
<div class="container" align="center">
    <td>Select Index :</td>
<select name="index1">
    {% for index1 in index %}
    <option>{{index1}}</option>
    {% endfor %}

</select>

    <br><br>
{% if index1 == index1 %}
<table border="1px" class="table table-dark" align="center">
    <tr>
        {% for key in key_list %}
        <th>{{key}}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
        {% for row2 in resp2 %}
    <tr>
        {% for key in key_list %}
        <td>{{row2[key]}}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</table>
{% else %}
<table border="1px">
</table>
{% endif %}
    <br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cari</button>
</div>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

can u guys tell me what wrong ? its my code or my elasticsearch is error ?  there is no error when i debug the app.py but cant access the url

Answer (score 0):

The return statement seems to be within the for loop. Could you un-indent it (remove the tab spacing on that line) and check again?

You may also need an else statement in case the request is not a POST request, because you've allowed both GET and POST methods on this view function.